# Where to store user id in jwt

Tags: jwt

I am generting a jwt for an api token.  I am putting the user id into that jwt so I know who is calling into the api.  Where do I put the user id in the jwt.

I have seen many different examples that put it in 'sub', 'aud' and even 'iss'.  Which is correct if any.  Or does user id go in a non registered name?

Answer (score 40):

The `sub` claim is the right claim for the user identifier. The `aud` claim identifies the intended recipient of the JWT and the `iss` identifies the issuer/creator. Any other interpretations of these claims are not standard compliant, see: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1

Comment: So there's no standard way for instance if I want a humanly readable ID *and* a more database friendly key that represents an id? Should I not even be storing an email as the `sub` claim and just use `internal id` whatever that may be.

Comment: @Simon_Weaver you may want to look through the registered claims listed here: https://www.iana.org/assignments/jwt/jwt.xhtml