# Explanations on JWT Tokens structure

Tags: jwt

I'm trying to understand JWT tokens usage but I'm getting lost on the theorycal part.

I have some questions about JWT Tokens structure, in order to make this question a sort of documentation for new users, providing it with a logic order, I will write them **in bold** below as long as I list a sample JWT content.

I will also summary them in the end of the question

---

A "classic" JWT token is composed as follows:

[HEADER].[PAYLOAD].[SIGNATURE]

In detail:

---

**HEADER**

```
{
  "alg": "HS256",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

Which contains the following fields:

- ALG = Encryption algorythm (using the default HS256 could be fine)
- TYP = simply tells that it's a JWT

---

**PAYLOAD**

```
{
  "sub": "1234567890",
  "name": "MrJohnDoe",
  "iat": 1516239022
}
```

- SUB = Is an OPTIONAL parameter. It's the subject of the token. (credits: see @cassiomolin answer)

According to: [Where to store user id in jwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32152574/where-to-store-user-id-in-jwt), it looks like you can use it to store your user ID in it.

- NAME = The username
- IAT = Token creation date and time, expressed in unix timestamp. (Thanks to @jps and @JeanRostan in the comments below)

---

**SIGNATURE**

```
HMACSHA256(
  base64UrlEncode(header) + "." +
  base64UrlEncode(payload),
  
secret

)
```

- SECRET = Unique key known just by the server. To not confuse with the current user password, which should never be used for this! (thanks to @jps in the comments below)

Comment: iat is a unix timestamp, it expresses the number of seconds elapsed since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) so it's a date indicating when the token won't be valid anymore. The wiki page on JWT tokens will answer your questions most likely: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token#Standard_fields

Comment: read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42058353/how-jwt-token-expiresin-works-in-feathers/42063121#42063121) about the timestamps format. IAT is issued at, the timestamp when the token was created. The expiration is in the exp claim.

Comment: @JeanRostan Understood! Thanks! What about "SUB" and "secret"? Can you please explain me what are they exaclty?

Comment: secret is a key used for the signature. And you should not use the users password. The secret should only be known on server side.

Comment: @jps That makes me a little bit less confused and a little bit more at the same time... I mean, thanks to your comment now I've understood but... What if i use both? Does a claim overcome to the other?

Comment: @jps All right, thanks! The last question is about the sub...Can you please explain me what does it contains exaclty?

Comment: @Deadpool you mean iat and exp? These are simply two different claims, one for the time of creation, the other for the end of it's life

Comment: @jps Understood (yes it was about IAT and EXP, but now this step is clear)

Comment: subject is to whom the token was issued.

Comment: @jps Do you mean for example the api controller who has generated it or the user who is logged in? I find this part a little complicated... Can you please explain me with a simple example? I think it will make me understand this completely

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is `sub`? Can you please provide me an example of what it could be in a common usage?

The `sub` claim identifies the principal that is the subject of the JWT. In other other, it can hold the username of the user who you issued the token to.

From the [RFC 7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519):

> [**4.1.2.  "sub" (Subject) Claim**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.2)
>
> The `sub` (subject) claim identifies the principal that is the
> subject of the JWT.  The claims in a JWT are normally statements
> about the subject.  The subject value MUST either be scoped to be
> locally unique in the context of the issuer or be globally unique.
> The processing of this claim is generally application specific. The
> `sub` value is a case-sensitive string containing a StringOrURI
> value.  Use of this claim is OPTIONAL.

Comment: Thanks! So it's not needed, good!
I was searching in a very deep way in the meantime and I found a rumor that said that "You can use sub to store your unique user ID". Is it a correct usage, in your opinion?

Comment: @Deadpool Yes, it's suitable for a unique user identifier.